# aws lambda parse excel file node failed Corrupted zip

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

on localhost it works.
running on aws lambda `amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0`

getting this error message

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "Error: End of data reached (data length = 14653, asked index = 23286). Corrupted zip ?",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "Error",
        "errorMessage": "End of data reached (data length = 14653, asked index = 23286). Corrupted zip ?",
        "stack": [
            "Error: End of data reached (data length = 14653, asked index = 23286). Corrupted zip ?",
            "    at NodeBufferReader.checkIndex (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:272:19)",
            "    at NodeBufferReader.checkOffset (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:263:14)",
            "    at NodeBufferReader.readData (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:634:10)",
            "    at NodeBufferReader.readString (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:321:49)",
            "    at ZipEntries.readBlockEndOfCentral (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:2198:39)",
            "    at ZipEntries.readEndOfCentral (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:2286:14)",
            "    at ZipEntries.load (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:2344:14)",
            "    at new ZipEntries (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:2168:14)",
            "    at JSZipSync.module.exports [as load] (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:581:18)",
            "    at new JSZipSync (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/jszip.js:528:14)",
            "    at zip_read (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:2973:24)",
            "    at read_zip (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:20892:8)",
            "    at readSync (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:20959:69)",
            "    at Object.readFileSync (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:20973:9)",
            "    at module.exports.CreateOrUpdateTenants (/var/task/src/lib/operations/tenants/tenants.js:14:25)",
            "    at kwargs (/var/task/node_modules/kwargs/kwargs.js:21:17)",
            "    at /var/task/src/routes/operations/tenants.js:18:5",
            "    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)",
            "    at next (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)",
            "    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53:37)",
            "    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:458:21)",
            "    at process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:120:14)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: End of data reached (data length = 14653, asked index = 23286). Corrupted zip ?",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
    ]
}
```

code is

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp' })

router.post('/route-api', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {

    var workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.file.path)

})
```

Comment: WebQube, I am having same issue - did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, My solution was to parse the excel on the frontend as json.

`Js (React)`

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);

reader.onload = async function (e) {
    let cfb = XLSX.read(e.target.result, {type: 'binary'});
      let sheetData = cfb.Sheets[cfb.SheetNames[0]];
      let jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheetData);
      ...
}
```